# Insert title of table of contents into toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a little bit of problem. I have to put the title of toc into toc.
I've used the following code to do that and it works for me, kind of.
The problem is in the title is aligned with the titles of the chapters and not with list of figures etc.

```
{
\makeatletter
\let\@oldstarttoc\@starttoc
\renewcommand{\@starttoc}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\contentsname}% Add ToC to ToC
  \@oldstarttoc
}
\tableofcontents
\makeatother
}
```

Here is the picture of my toc.

[image]

My idea is to use the same code for  Acknowledgements, Lists of... , Abbreviations etc.
Is it ok to try that or there is an alternative?

Comment: Lovely question: my problem, at least with Google docs, is the inverse: making sure that the header of table of contents does not show in the table of contents.

Comment: Just drop the `\protect\numberline{}` in your definition.

Comment: What is the point of adding the Acknowledgements and the Table of Contents to the Table of Contents? The ToC is supposed to help readers find the parts that are interesting to them. Once they reach the ToC, they supposedly have already seen the Acknowledgements and the ToC, so what is there to find?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you simply load the package [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) that automatically inserts ToC, LoF and LoT into the ToC itself?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: It works but spacings are bigger than it should be. I'll try to force the spacing somehow.

Comment: @ManuelCalavera Which spacing?

Comment: @ karlkoeller Spacing inside toc. It probably has to do something with my class file.

Comment: @ManuelCalavera I suggest you to ask a new question containing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows this.